# Parse API not accesiblie from Romania?

Tags: networking, parse-platform

My parse powered application for iOS worked great until 2 weeks ago when the users could not connect to my parse databases. I examined the problem and I observed that if I use my IP, I could not access parse APIs but using a USA/UK VPN does the trick without any problem.
I tried my 3G connection, different public WiFIs from the city, nothing worked.
people around the globe can access too, the problem is with IPs from Romania.

Does anyone know about this or a possible fix?

The application is live in appstore so the code and everything is the same as at the time when was fully functional.

UPDATE: I also updated the parse sdk to the latest version, build and tested the app but same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems it was a parse temporary error, it's fixed now.